# excel VBA (not VBScript) 101: How do I create and read a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, excel-2010, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have a macro that needs to load OData results into an in-memory array.  The only part I'm missing is how to actually create that array in Excel.

> How do I create a multi-dimensional array (or an array of a class) in
>   Excel 2010?

The only constraint I have is that anything I build must be self contained in the XLSX.  So that means dependencies on PowerPivot, addins, etc, are out.  I think that leaves me with just VBScript macros.

I've searched MSDN, StackOverflow, and Google for hours and can't find a clear-cut example of how to do this.

Comment: To be clear, the macro language in Excel is **VBA**.  VBScript is a much more limited language than VBA, so your answers would be very different asking about one versus the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an extension to @Jeremy 's answer:

you CAN redim multi dimensional arrays.

```
DIM arr() as Variant 'or object or class or whatever.  
Redim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1) 'works 
Redim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 3) 'works, but deletes any existing data
Redim Preserve arr(1 To 3, 1 To 10) 'works and keeps any data
Redim Preserve arr(1 To 10, 1 To 10) 'fails, you can only redm preserve the last dimension
```

Whether Arrays, Collections (or Dictionaries for that matter) are best for your app depends on the details of your application

Answer (score 2):

Open Excel

Press Alt + F11

Right click on VBAProject > Insert > Class

Specify the Name for the VBA class "Person" in the left hand pane, properties dialog

Give the Person class a property eg firstname

```
Public FirstName As String
```

Create a second class or module file and here is how to create/access an array of the People class:

```
Public colOfPeople As New Collection

Public Function MakePeople() As String

Dim clsP As New clsPerson
clsP.FirstName = "Jeremy"

colOfPeople.Add (clsP)

End Function
```

**Solution 1: To make this multi-dimensional, I've made the collection an array:**

```
Public multiColOfPeople() As New Collection

Public Function MakeMultiPeople() As String

ReDim Preserve colOfPeople(1) 'dimension multi-array collection
Dim clsP As New clsPerson
clsP.FirstName = "Jeremy"
colOfPeople(0).Add (clsP)

Dim clsP1 As New clsPerson
clsP1.FirstName = "Lisa"
colOfPeople(1).Add (clsP1)

End Function
```

**Solution 2: Using a multi-dimensional array (no collection)**

```
Public multiArray(3, 3) As New clsPerson

Dim clsP As New clsPerson
'store
multiArray(0, 1) = clsP
'retrieve
clsP = multiArray(0, 1)
```

**Edit ***

To use the second solution, see chris neilsen's answer for info on ReDim'ing multidimensional arrays

Comment: I'm unable to rename the left hand class in excel.  Right clicking, saving, and clicking once on the name and waiting produce no results.  Not to mention I am a little unsure what to name them.  I'm guessing `clsPerson`?

Comment: aaah... it's in the properties dialog box.  I'm able to rename my class only in that screen.  I'll see if I can enumerate and create my array.

Comment: Which solution above supports dynamic growth? My proof of concept code uses `ReDim Preserve myArray(UBound(myArray) + 1)`

Comment: Doesn't work for me... assiging a string or a variable returns: `Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object`. Then I changed the property from String to object and got this error: `Object variable or With block variable not set`.  Perhaps I need to do something different with `clsPerson` with regard to Excel 2010?

Comment: @makerofthings7 - please see edit, sorry for leading you up the garden path

Comment: Thank you Jeremy... Are the parenthesis needed? The solution that worked for me involved [deleting the parens.  See (Storing Multiple Objects In A Collection)](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: In Unmanaged VB, parenthesis after a varible name (not after datatype) is how u make arrays. I fixed my answer - 1st error due to firstname being a function not a propert (procedure), 2nd error maybe use Set multiArray(0,1)=clsP